# How to format (credit card) numbers with 16 digits into 4 groups in a cell

Tags: google-sheets, format

I have a column with credit card numbers, where every digit is entered plainly in a string: `4805123412344564`. Now I want them to be shown with digits grouped by four. So I assign the number format `0000 0000 0000 0000` and got the number displayed as expected: `4805 1234 1234 4564`.

But when I now enter a new number in this very cell this is then shown in plain string again: `4805123412344564`. When I check the assigned format (Format → Number) it still shows the check hook right before this very format entry: `0000 0000 0000 0000`. I can now click this entry again (although already selected) and then the format is correct as desired. But I don't want to!

What can I do making the number to appear the desired way without reassigning the format again? I've tried also with `#### #### #### ####` and `0000" "0000" "0000" "0000` without any different behaviour.

Comment: You have to select the entire column and apply the format you need.

Comment: @TheMaster Yes, I did that. But no matter if I assign the format to a column, area or single cell - same result. ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

I think this is actually impossible using number formatting, because Google Sheets (inherited from Excel) doesn't support >15 significant digits in numbers. Your example of 4805123412344564 actually becomes 4805 1234 1234 4560 (16th digit lost) when the number format 0000 0000 0000 0000 is used.

One alternative would be to use string manipulation on your column of plain numbers to generate another column formulaically with the numbers in the correct format. If your credit card numbers are in column A, you could use:

```
=map(tocol(A:A,1),lambda(each,join(" ",regexextract(each,"(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{4})"))))
```

Comment: Thank You very much for the workaround. But if it is actually impossible how comes the formatting works for the moment it was applied? It only fails when a new value is entered.

Comment: I think the answer relates to the fact that the 16 digit entry in the cell is interpreted as text by default because of it's length. Applying the number format forces Sheets to coerce the text value to a number, which can apply the format (but inevitably reduces the precision by 1sf). Maybe this is intentional behaviour (to ensure that the user doesn't inadvertently reduce the precision of a real number without realising)?

Comment: Sounds plausbile. But isn't there a way to format a string by groups? I. e. ```$$$$ $$$$ $$$$ $$$$```

Comment: No, there's no such concept as a 'custom text format' in Sheets analogous to that of custom number formats. I imagine it is possible to use Apps Script to modify cell contents immediately after entry to generate the required pattern, but I'm not familiar enough with scripting to advise how this should be coded.

Answer (score 2):

Storing as a number would be problematic. That is because Google Sheet likely uses IEEE 754 double to store floating point representation for large numbers, which gives 15-17 significant digits, whereas credit card numbers have 16 digits.

You can however perform your own formatting conversion as text. For example,

```js
=let(input,A1:A,
     arrayformula(if(input<>"",
                     left(to_text(input),4)&" "&mid(input,5,4)&" "&mid(input,9,4)&" "&right(input,4),
                     )))
```

Note that formatting cells as grouped text is not an option currently. (It'd be equivalent as substring and regex patterns anyway, which we already have formulas for.)

Answer (score 2):

Another formula-based approach:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,"\d{4}","$0 ")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers, you cannot save a 16-digit number in a single cell. If you need to process the credit card numbers as numbers down the road, it might be more convenient to split the credit card numbers into 2 halves, each formatted as a Google Sheet number.

Most simple things such as comparisons (e.g. for ordering, matching) already works with text, albeit less efficiently in the background. But just to mention this possibility, since storing credit numbers with whitespaces in-between can turn out inconvenient for comparisons later on.

For example,

```js
=let(data,A1:A
    ,arrayformula(if(isblank(data)
                    ,
                    ,value({left(data,8),right(data,8)}))))
```

followed with manual format settings for the columns.

---

The same formula can of course be modified to show text in 1 cell, notwithstanding earlier points.

```js
=let(data,A1:A
    ,arrayformula(if(isblank(data)
                    ,
                    ,textjoin(" ",false
                             ,text({left(data,8),right(data,8)},"#### ####")))))
```

The true implication of the latter formula though is that [`text`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139?hl=en) doesn't work directly without splitting the credit card number column first because it does not accept 16-digit numbers as Google Sheet numbers, but as text instead.